# How to pass a string with a few comma separated values as function parameters

Tags: php, function-parameter

For instance:

```
$str = '1, 2, 4, 13';
```

I'd like the effect to be as if it were:

```
func(1, 2, 4, 13)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$params = explode(', ', $str);
call_user_func_array("func", $params);
```

Comment: Beware that this will only work if the arguments are explicitly separated by a comma followed by a space. You might want to do some post-processing to ensure that they're the right datatype.

Comment: @theazureshadow Very true. I just intended to answer the example as written. But yeah if it's different, you might want to split by comma alone, then trim() the elements. Something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I was just mentioning that for the OP's sake. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '1, 2, 4, 13';
function func($one, $two, $three, $four) {
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}
call_user_func_array('func', explode(', ', $str));
```

Remember, you can pass as many parameters to a function and accessing them with [func_get_args()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.func-get-args.php), they dont have to be defined in the methods signature.