# how do you convert a hex to rgb so that it can be used with imagecolourset?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an image that I would like to change the colour of based on the colour set by a variable. The problem I have is that the value comes from the data source as a hex and imagecolourset works with rgb.
I have set up a conversion function:

```
    function hex2rgb($hex) {
 $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

 if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
  $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
  $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
  $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
} else {
  $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
  $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
  $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
}
 $rgb = array($r, $g, $b);
  return implode(",", $rgb); // returns the rgb values separated by commas

}
```

and then use this like so:

```
 $homeRGB = hex2rgb($homeColour);
 imagecolorset($him,$hindex, $homeRGB);
```

but I get an error message saying that imagecolorset only excepts 5 parameters and there are only 3 set. the result should print 225,225,225 so I don't understand why it is reading it as only 1 parameter instead of 3. if I manually put in 225,225,225 then the code works fine. Not sure where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a variable of the data type STRING, when the PHP function [imagecolorset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php) instead requires you to pass the rgb-values as three separate parameters of data type INTEGER.

In general, PHP is rather tolerant when it comes to [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), but you [can not pass a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669717/how-to-pass-a-string-with-a-few-comma-separated-values-as-function-parameters) as a function parameter expecting the content of that string to be treated as separate parameters. It will be treated as one parameter, even if the string contains commas.

Instead change your function to return an array:

```
 function hex2rgb($hex) {
    $hex = str_replace("#", "", $hex);

     if(strlen($hex) == 3) {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,1).substr($hex,0,1));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,1,1).substr($hex,1,1));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,1).substr($hex,2,1));
    } else {
      $r = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
      $g = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
      $b = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
    }
    return array($r, $g, $b); // RETURN ARRAY INSTEAD OF STRING
}
```

And then use it like:

```
$homeRGB = hex2rgb($homeColour);
imagecolorset($him,$hindex, $homeRGB[0], $homeRGB[1], $homeRGB[2]);
```

If you for some reason absolutely can't or won't alter the `hex2rgb`-function, a workaround would be to use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$homeRGB = hex2rgb($homeColour);
call_user_func_array('imagecolorset', array_merge(array($him, $hindex), explode(',', $homeRGB)));
```

It's not recommended though because of the overhead of unnecessary  imploding and exploding etc..

Comment: I had tried to turn the result into integers using a different method but that didn't work. Thanks so much for your help :-)